# How to disable GPU or PCIe bus power?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci-express

I have PC with dedicated (power hungry) GPU. I don't need it's power for most time and need to save power (sometimes I use this PC on UPS and GPU takes about 35W at idle) so I must physically remove the GPU.

I need to disable it's power (from software or even a HW switch). I know that there are risers from x1 to x16 which allow (require) connection of external 8-pin PSU, but I'd like to keep my full x16 speed.

Are there any devices (like MOSFET switches or even relays) allowing me to do that or (better) is there any way doing it from software (I tried Googling it and found only unanswered questions) or at least something like riser allowing me to connect external power to PCIe x16 (I will make the switch myself). I have no idea how these can be called to shop for (and is this even manufactured).

Comment: Some computers have a BIOS/UEFI setting for that. What is your computer model (motherboard and firmware version would help).

Comment: no, I don't have this option in my setup (it was first place where I looked)

Comment: Is addition to the comment asking for the computer model and/or motherboard, which operating system is in use?

Comment: The [PCI Express® Base Specification Revision 4.0 Version 0.3](https://astralvx.com/storage/2020/11/PCI_Express_Base_4.0_Rev0.3_February19-2014.pdf) defines a _Power Controller_, which if present allows software to turn on or off power to a slot. E.g. see the definition of the _Power Controller Control_ bit in the _Slot Control Register (Offset 18h)_. The _Power Controller_ is part of _PCI Express Hot-Plug Support_ which not all motherboards support.

Comment: @ChesterGillon my motherboard is from dell optiplex 7010 and OS used is win 10 dualbooting with ubuntu 22.04 lts

Comment: @samkiavtk Can you run ``sudo lspci -vvv | grep PwrCtrl`` under Ubuntu. If a PCIe slot in your motherboard has a _Power Controller_ to turn off power, you will see a ``PwrCtrl+``. If only see ``PwrCtrl-`` there are no Power Controllers for the slots.

Comment: @ChesterGillon unfortunately it's pwrctrl- (also all other things are -)

Answer (score -1):

If your BIOS/UEFI doesn't provide an option to disable integrated graphics,
you can still do it this way:

- Run Device Manager
- Expand the "Display adapters" section and find the integrated graphics
  adapter
- Right-click the integrated graphics adapter and select "Disable device"
- Confirm the action if prompted.

Comment: thi is not what I'm asking for, I need to disable dedicated gpu to save power

Comment: You can do exactly the same with any display adapter.

Comment: [Does Disabling a PCI Device in Windows Device Manager Shut Off Power?](https://superuser.com/a/709837/1731245) has a link to [D3cold substate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/device-sleeping-states?redirectedfrom=MSDN#d3cold-substate). I'm not quite sure how much power can be saved be disabling a device in Windows.

Comment: @ChesterGillon: Hopefully most of the power, but this depends on many variables: The device itself, the motherboard and the driver. There's not one answer for all contexts.

Comment: I don't think it does as the gpu stays spining it's fans and heats up a little (like when taking about 35W)

Comment: Please give details of your computer, GPU and motherboard.